Flink SQL not reporting results when using window_start and window_end in the select statement
I am using FLinkSQL on Confluent Cloud and I have a topic where I am getting input data from. I tried creating a tumbling window to calculate aggregate for one of the fields but the resulting output only shows up if I use either window_start or window_end but not both. I tried it with a tutorial and it worked fine but I am not able to understand why this is happening with my custom data.
Confluent allows us to use $rowtime as time attribute for windowing operations if there is no timestamp in the record's value.
My sample data within the topic looks like this: {"storeId": "1001", "sku": "SKU3", "quantity": -2}
My tumbling window query:
SELECT
  window_start,window_end,sku,storeId,
  SUM(quantity) AS total
FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE sku_input_avro, DESCRIPTOR($rowtime), INTERVAL '20' SECOND))
GROUP BY window_start,window_end,sku,storeId;

I tried switching between JSON Schema and Avro but to no avail. I even pumped 100s of records incase the watermarking strategy only kicks in after a threshold. None worked so far.
